# Change buttonText in ext.msg.confirmation popup

Tags: extjs

I want to change the text from "yes" to "YES!!!" and "no" to "NO!!!" I tried many things but nothing seems to be working,
Couldnt find any documents on Sencha for this, if anyone can please help, Thank you

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirmation', "Do you want to cancel the order?", function(btnText){
                //btnText = {
                //    yes: "YES!!",
               //   no: "NO!!"
               //}, 
               //btnText.setText("YESSS!!"),    
                if(btnText === "yes"){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "You have cancelled the order.");
               }
               else if(btnText === "no"){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "You have confirmed 'No'.");

               }
            }, this);
    }
});
```

[Solution]

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function() {                
        Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Message',
        buttons: {
           yes: 'Cancel preAuth',
           no: 'Cancel the whole order',
           cancel: 'Do nothing!'
        },  
              fn: function(buttonValue, inputText, showConfig) {
                if(buttonValue === "yes"){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "You have cancelled the order.");
               }
               else if(buttonValue === "no"){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "You have confirmed 'No'.");
               }
            }, this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ext.Msg.show` instead of `Ext.Msg.confirm`, and set `buttonText` for custom button texts. Check [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.MessageBox.html#property-buttonText) and try the following code:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Message',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
    buttonText: {
        yes: 'MyYes',
        no: 'MyNo',
        cancel: 'MyCancel'
    },
    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
    fn: function (btn) {
        if (btn === 'yes') {
            console.log('MyYes');
        } else if (btn === 'no') {
            console.log('MyNo');
        } else {
            console.log('MyCancel');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If I use buttons and buttonText both, in that case buttonText wasnt working for me, posted the solution in my problem statement, Thank you !!!